# How to control numbers of container running inside Job on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've one Job that has 500 containers, each container run a different file. But I'm try to execute 10 containers by time, but the parallelism is for the pod and not the containers.

Is there any way to control the parallelism in containers levels ?

Answer (score 1):

> Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can
> create and manage in Kubernetes.

So, the answer is no.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/

Comment: To expand on this a little, not only is having multiple containers in one pod committing to running all or none of them, but they will all run on the same node.  Typical best practice is to run _one_ container per pod.  Running 500 separate Jobs would be fine.